# Outlook 2007 cannot delete rules

Tags: exchange-2007, outlook

I have a user who created a mess of rules that are causing issues. When I delete them on her Outlook, and close Outlook and go back to look at the rules they are all still there.

I don't understand why they are not deleting. Sometimes it will warn me that the client and the server rules don't match and asks which one I want to keep – client or server. No matter which one I select, the rules are all still there.

Any experiences with this?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the command line options still exist in [Outlook 2007](http://www.petri.co.il/outlook_2003_command_line_switches.htm) to clear the rules out.

```
/CleanRules          # delete all rules
/CleanClientRules    # delete client rules
/CleanServerRules    # delete server rules
```

I have seen some weird cases where you couldn't remove rules from the GUI, but the command line switches where able to remove them.  Backup your rules first if you need to save any of them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ran these, got no errors or anything...and the darn rules are still there.